# C# show XML in WebBrowser or any other component

Tags: c#, xml, browser

What I really need is to show XML in a component. Till now I have utilized webbrowser component to show my XML data here is the code:

```
//XDocument loaded_xml = new XDocument();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        loaded_xml.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        WebBrowser1.DocumentStream = stream;
```

the problem is that it's not render the xml in my webbrowser, but when I right+click on it and view source the xml content is there!!

Finally, if there is any other component to show XML in it I will be glad to learn that:)
Thanks in advance...

Comment: is that helpful to you ?

Comment: Actually I prefer to show the raw XML not populating it like treeView, but thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

There is an explanation [here](http://blorgh.wordpress.com/2006/10/17/displaying-xml-in-the-net-webbrowser-control/) about using the default XSL used by IE.

**This is copy-pasted from that article**, since it doesn't seem accessible to you. **Credit goes to the author**:

Internet Explorer displays XML in a pretty decent manner. Today I figured I would use the same engine to display XML in a .NET 2.0 application. So I dropped a WebBrowser control on to a form, and assigned my XML string to the DocumentText property. Voila? Of course not.

After some digging, I found that IE uses a built-in XSLT-transform to present XML as HTML in the browser. The stylesheet in question is available from the following uri in IE: res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl. Ok then, so one can just save this string, and use it in .NET? Not quite. As it turns out, the XSL that IE uses is not compatible with .NET’s XslCompiledTransform class. D’oh!

After some more digging, it turns out that Steve Muench has done the conversion to the XSLT 1.0 REC that .NET requires. Thanks, man! The file can be downloaded here.

I added the following code to my WebBrowser base class, to allow developers to display XML by setting a property:

```
public XmlDocument DocumentXml
{
set
{
Stream s = <defaultss.xsl from embedded resource file>

XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(s);
XslCompiledTransform xct = new XslCompiledTransform();
xct.Load(xr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
xct.Transform(value, xw);

this.DocumentText = sb.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: dude the aforementioned link is corrupted (404 not-found)

Comment: Works for me: http://blorgh.wordpress.com/2006/10/17/displaying-xml-in-the-net-webbrowser-control/

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I found a solution which is not perfect but working... first I save my XML in a file and then load it with webbroser.Navigate(path); and volla it works:)

Comment: @Ehsan : +1 for mention of the Navigate() method.